# SQL Procedure Meaning

Tags: sql-server

Can someone to explain me what the next procedure does?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [add_100*Clients-runView2-del_50*Reductions] AS
DECLARE @procName NVARCHAR(100) = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID), @currentName NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @index int

INSERT INTO TestRuns (Description, StartAt, EndAt)  
VALUES ('Add Clients - View 2 - Delete Reductions', GETDATE(), null)
DECLARE @currentID int
SET @currentID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())

SET @index = CHARINDEX('-', @procName) 
WHILE @index > 0
BEGIN
    SET @currentName = SUBSTRING(@procName, 1, @index-1)
    SET @procName = SUBSTRING(@procName, @index+1, (LEN(@procName) - @index))
    SET @index = CHARINDEX('-', @procName)
    EXEC @currentName       
END
SET @currentName = @procName
EXEC @currentName

UPDATE TestRuns
SET EndAt = GETDATE()
WHERE TestRunID = @currentID

GO
```

I can't understand what does getDate and how it influences the tables.

Comment: Getdate() just returns the current date and time.  Is that all you are having trouble with?  Because this is one crazy hack of a stored procedure...

Comment: In this case `GETDATE()` is being used to adjust the `TestRuns` table `startAt` and `endAt` columns.

Comment: and what's the purpose of this procedure?

Comment: GETDATE() is date and timestamping when the proc starts (StartAt) and when it finishes (EndAt).  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx which is being stored in TestRuns

Comment: The main part is running a loop, parsing procedure names out of the name of this procedure, running them in turn. So it runs `[add_100*Clients]`, `[runView2]`, and `[del_50*Reductions]`. Before and after that loop, it is saving the start and end time for the full run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the procedure lies within
`EXEC @currentName`.

I believe this is some sort of performance test where you see how much time  procedures takes to run
I guess you are passing some sort of procedure names separated by `-` and parse each procedure and run them.

While running them , you are recording your start of the time using `GetDate` and after everything is run, end of the run using `GetDate`.(As `GetDate` gives you the current time, the difference will tell you how long did it take to run all the procedures.

You record that information in an `audit` table called `TestRuns`.